# Chrome Console Automatic Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I'm on a website that forces me to click numerous elements on the page

This is the code for the elements

```
<span class="icon icon-arrow-2"></span>
```

Is it possible to tell me the code to write into the console of google chrome to click all the elements on the page named "icon icon-arrow-2" at once?

Comment: try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Hh6wU/1/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('icon icon-arrow-2');
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {      
  items[i].click();
}
```

Or if there is jQuery on the page:

```
$('.icon.icon-arrow-2').click();
```

Comment: one more question though, for the jQuery, is there any way to loop the command?